# Prove that the trace of $\alpha$ is contained in a sphere of radius $r>0$ if and only if $\frac{1}{k(s)^2}+\frac{k'(s)^2}{k(s)^4\tau(s)^2}=r^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, proof-explanation

$\textbf{preliminaries}$

I am in the course of geometry of curves and surfaces, clearly frenet's trihedron is $\{T(s),N(s),B(s)\}$ where $T(s)=\alpha'(s)$ , $N(s)=\frac{T'(s)}{\|T'(s)\|}$ and $B(s)=T(s) \times N(s)$
The Serret-Frenet equations of the curve $\alpha$ are:

$$T'(s)=k(s)N(s)$$
$$N'(s)=-k(s)T(s)-\tau(s)B(s)$$
$$B'(s)=\tau(s)N(s)$$

$\textbf{Question}$
Let $\alpha: I \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a curve p.b.a.l. With positive curvature such that $k'(s)\not = 0$ and $\tau(s)\not = 0$ for each $s\in I$. Prove that the trace of $\alpha$ is contained in a sphere of radius $r>0$ if and only if
$$\frac{1}{k(s)^2}+\frac{k'(s)^2}{k(s)^4\tau(s)^2}=r^2$$

$\textbf{My attempt:}$

If the trace of $\alpha$ lies in a sphere of radius $r>0$, then $\|\alpha\|^2=r^2$ Differentiating this expression three times, we have:
$$\langle \alpha,T \rangle=0$$
$$1+k\langle \alpha, N \rangle=0$$ and
$$k'\langle \alpha, N\rangle -k\tau \langle \alpha, B \rangle=0$$ therefore:
$r^2=\|\alpha\|^2=\langle \alpha , T \rangle^2+\langle \alpha, N \rangle^2+ \langle \alpha, B\rangle^2=(\frac{1}{k})^2+(\frac{k'}{\tau k^2})^2$.

Here I assumed the following equality $\|\alpha\|^2=\langle \alpha , T \rangle^2+\langle \alpha, N \rangle^2+ \langle \alpha, B\rangle^2$ but in reality I don't know how to justify it, can you tell me how to justify this equality?

conversely this turns out

$\textbf{imagge attached}$

[image]

Comment: I'm confused - What is $\alpha$ and what is its trace?

Comment: @K.defaoite $\alpha$ is a curve p.b.l.a, see my question.

Comment: What does p.b.l.a stand for?

Comment: parameterized by arc length

Comment: This identical question was posted a few days ago. There are dozens of posts on spherical curves. Why don't you search the site before posting?

Comment: @TedShifrin Give me the link of the identical question

Comment: There is one. There are lots, lots more. Just search.

Comment: NO NO!! My question is just a detail you have ignored

Comment: @TedShifrin you should consider reading my question before closing other questions

Comment: And here is another one from a few days ago. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3933223/question-about-curvature/3933378#3933378  But you're right. Your question has nothing to do with differential geometry. Go review what it means to have an orthonormal basis for $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: and you keep making your videos on youtube